# Detect "Suplemental language support" on Windows XP

Tags: .net, windows-xp, globalization

I need a way to programatically determine if this checkbox in control panel is checked (Windows XP):

Screenshot:

[image]

The checkbox is in Control Panel - Regional settings - Language - Supplemental language support - and is called "Install files for complex script and right-to-left languages".

It would be best to check for some related registry entry, but I do not know which one. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250564/how-to-check-from-c-are-files-for-complex-script-and-rtl-languages-installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the same API which I describe in [Detect if any right-to-left language is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434234/detect-if-any-right-to-left-language-is-installed/3434825#3434825) can be used to verify that the corresponding right-to-left languages are installed.