# Treeview encoding problems with some languages on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, treeview

In the treeview I use a different language from their encodings. In Windows 7, everything looks good:

[image]

But in Windows XP there are problems with some languages​​:

[image]

The same problem with the other types of controls (e.g. webbrowser, messagebox).

Here [Breaks encoding in richtextbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591369/breaks-encoding-in-richtextbox), I solved the problem with the richtextbox, but it appeared to Windows XP.

Is there a way to fix it all on the XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different/larger font such as `Lucida Sans Unicode` As per the question on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1ed344a-ccc3-4800-82e5-62059472f7d7/encoding-toubles-with-some-unicode-characters-on-xp-c-net).

Comment: It did not help. As I understand it the only way to fix this - "Install files for complex script and right-to-left languages".

Comment: So when you follow [these instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/int_pr_install_complex_languages.mspx?mfr=true) does it work?

Comment: Yes it works. But I wanted to normal mapping without manipulation by the user to the operating system.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't handle this from the application. But you may be able to query that the client has the capability to show those fonts (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250564/how-to-check-from-c-are-files-for-complex-script-and-rtl-languages-installed)).

Comment: Although it might be possible to have your installation procedures set the language capability (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289125))